# Elasticsearch wildcard query add second parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

If I want to add Wildcard search to this ES query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "fieldA": "{{fieldA}}" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then the Wildcard query becomes -

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "fieldA",
      "query": "{{fieldA}}"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I have 2 parameters in the first ES query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "fieldA": "{{fieldA}}" } },
        { "match": { "fieldB": "{{fieldB}}" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What would the ES query with Wilcard be?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a more complex string for the query: *fieldA:this AND fieldB:that*.

Comment: Since the default_field is fieldA in first example, and now we need fieldB as well here, how do you suggest the final query to look like?

Comment: Well, I think I have specified "fieldB" in the query string, didn't I?

Comment: Is this how you are suggesting?

{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "fieldA",
      "query": "{{fieldA}} AND {{fieldB}}"
    }
  }
}

Comment: No, here: `"query": { "query_string": { "query": "fieldA:fieldAValue AND fieldB:fieldBValue" } }`. I don't quite understand why you're eager to use `default_field` (it's not obligatory) and `query_string` at all - you will get the scoring with `bool.must` query as well.